# NullPointerException при запросе в БД

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Возможно вопрос окажется бредовым, но я к сожалению решить проблему не могу. Стек используемых технологий, Spring + Hibernate + PostgreSQL.

Итак есть Контроллер для работы REST сервиса, вот его код работающий без ошибок:

```
@Controller
public class AdministratorController {

@RequestMapping("/admin/")
@ResponseBody
public String indexAdmin() {
    return "Панель Администратора";
}

@RequestMapping("/admin/startupdate")
@ResponseBody
public List<Avtor> startUpdateAvtor(Boolean launch) {
    String outtext;
    List<Avtor> avtorlist = new ArrayList();
    AdministratorController admin = new AdministratorController();
    if(launch){
        outtext = "Обновление авторов запущено";
        avtorlist = avtorDao.getAll();
    }else{
        outtext = "Обновление авторов остановлено";
    }
    return avtorlist;
}

public List<Avtor> checkUpdate(){

    List<Avtor> avtorlist = avtorDao.getAll();        
    return avtorlist;
}

@Autowired
private AvtorDao avtorDao = new AvtorDao();

@Autowired
private LkatDao lkatDao = new LkatDao();

@Autowired
private LworkDao lworkDao = new LworkDao();

}
```

Есть модель сущности БД вот ее пример:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Avtor"
,schema="public"
)
public class Avtor implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@NotNull
@Type(type = "text")
private String urladdress;

@Type(type = "text")
private String avtorname;

private String update_avtor;


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "avtor")
@JsonManagedReference
private Set<Lkat> lkat = new HashSet<>();

public Set<Lkat> getLkat() {
    return this.lkat;
}

public void setLkat(Set<Lkat> lkat) {
    this.lkat = lkat;
}

public void addLkat(Lkat lkat) {
    lkat.setAvtor(this);
    this.lkat.add(lkat);
}

//далее следуют конструкторы, геттеры и сеттеры 

}
```

Так же привожу пример DAO класса:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class AvtorDao {

public void create(Avtor avtor) {
    entityManager.persist(avtor);
    return;
}

public void delete(Avtor avtor) {
    if (entityManager.contains(avtor))
        entityManager.remove(avtor);
    else
    entityManager.remove(entityManager.merge(avtor));
    return;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Avtor> getAll() {
    return entityManager.createQuery("from Avtor").getResultList();
}

public List<Avtor> getByUrladdress(String urladdress) {
    return entityManager.createQuery(
        "from Avtor where urladdress = :urladdress")
        .setParameter("urladdress", urladdress)
        .getResultList();
}

public Avtor getByAvtorname(String avtorname) {
    return (Avtor) entityManager.createQuery(
        "from Avtor where avtorname = :avtorname")
        .setParameter("avtorname", avtorname)
        .getSingleResult();
}

public Avtor getById(long id) {
    return entityManager.find(Avtor.class, id);
}

public void update(Avtor avtor) {
    entityManager.merge(avtor);
    return;
}

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

Вопрос в следующем, почему при вызове метода `checkUpdate()` в методе `startUpdateAvtor(Boolean launch)` выпадает ошибка

```
2016-06-21 23:15:34.889 ERROR 5804 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at prodinfo.models.AvtorDao.getAll(AvtorDao.java:57) ~[classes/:na]
    at prodinfo.controllers.AdministratorController.checkUpdate(AdministratorController.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
    at prodinfo.controllers.AdministratorController.startUpdateAvtor(AdministratorController.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
```

Метод `startUpdateAvtor(Boolean launch)` выглядит следующим образом:

```
@RequestMapping("/admin/startupdate")
@ResponseBody
public List<Avtor> startUpdateAvtor(Boolean launch) {
    String outtext;
    List<Avtor> avtorlist = new ArrayList();
    AdministratorController admin = new AdministratorController();
    if(launch){
        outtext = "Обновление авторов запущено";
        avtorlist = admin.checkUpdate();
    }else{
        outtext = "Обновление авторов остановлено";
    }
    return avtorlist;
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, где я допустил ошибку?

Comment: entityManager не определен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смысл Dependency Injection, в том, что вы не должны создавать объекты вручную.

1. Вы помечаете необходимые компоненты приложения аннотациями: `@Service`, `@Component`, `@Repository` и т.д.
2. В том месте приложения, где вам нужен данный компонент приложения, вы можете получить его через аннотацию `@Autowired`, это и называется внедрение зависимости. Инжектить можно через

**поле**

```
@Autowired
private Foo foo;
```

**сеттер**

```
private Foo foo;

@Autowired
public setFoo(Foo foo) { this.foo = foo }
```

**конструктор**

```
class Foo {

    private Bar bar;

    @Autowired
    public Foo(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

[Подробнее тут](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s11.html)

3. На старте приложения Spring сканирует все компоненты и внедряет затребованные зависимости.

Если вы делаете вот это `private AvtorDao avtorDao = new AvtorDao();`, т.е. создаете объект в обход контекста Spring, то должны передать данному компоненту его зависимости вручную, например через сеттер.

Примерно так должен выглядеть ваш контроллер:

```
@Controller
public class AdministratorController {

    @Autowired
    private AvtorDao avtorDao;

    @RequestMapping("/admin/")
    public String indexAdmin() {
        return "admin";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/admin/startupdate")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Avtor> startUpdateAvtor() {
        return avtorDao.getAll();
    }

}
```